# Parsing PDF tables into csv with php

Tags: php, regex

I need to convert a pdf file with tables into CSV, so I used "PDFPARSER" in order to parse the entire text, then with pregmatch_all search the patterns of each table so I can create an array from each table of the pdf.

The structure of the following PDF is:

[image]

When I parse I get this

ECO-698 Acondicionador Frio-Calor ECO-CHI-522 Chimenea eléctrica con patas

I figured out how to pregmatch_all all the ECO-XXXXX, but I don't know how to pregmatch all the descriptions

This is what is working for ECO-XXXXXX

```
$parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
$pdf    = $parser->parseFile('publication.pdf');

$text = $pdf->getText();
echo $text;

$pattern = '/ECO-[.-^*-]{3,}| ECO-[.-^*-]{4,}\s\b[NMB]\b|ECO-[.-^*-]{4,}\sUP| ECO-[.-^*-]{3,}\sUP\s[B-N-M]{1}| ECO-[.-^*-]{3,}\sRX/' ;
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $array);

echo "<hr>";
print_r($array);
```

I get

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => ECO-698 [1] => ECO-CHI-522 [2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this regex:

```
(ECO[^\s]+)\s+(.*?)(?=ECO|\z)
```

As per the input string, group1 contains the ECO Block and group 2 contains the descriptions.

Explanation:

1. `(ECO[^\s]+)` capture full ECO block untill it reaches white space.
2. `\s+`one or more white space
3. `(.*?)(?=ECO|\z)` Here (.*?) matches description and `(?=ECO|\z)` is a positive look ahead to match `ECO` or end of string (`\z`)

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wbuCAE/1)

Source Code ([Run here](https://3v4l.org/MsDlc)):

```
$re = '/(ECO[^\s]+)\s+(.*?)(?=ECO|\z)/m';
$str = 'ECO-698 Acondicionador Frio-Calor ECO-CHI-522 Chimenea eléctrica con patas';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
$val=1;
foreach ($matches as $value)
    {

        echo "\n\nRow  no:".$val++;
        echo "\ncol 1:".$value[1]."\ncol 2:".$value[2];

    }
```

> UPDATE AS per the comment:

```
((?:ECO-(?!DE)[^\s]+)(?: (?:RX|B|N|M|UP|UP B|UP N|UP M))?)\s+(.*?)(?=(?:ECO-(?!DE))|\z)
```

[Regex 101 updated](https://regex101.com/r/1vjxC7/6)

Comment: Seems to be working, but i forgot to tell you that the are some ECO- that are ECO-8200-2 X This last "X" could be (B,N,M,UP,UP B,UP N,UP M). Also ECO-XXXX RX and ignore ECO-DE. How i do it if there is some whitespaces? Thank you very much

Comment: I basically dont get your comment clearly.. please give few more set of input and expected output

Comment: this is the full text https://regex101.com/r/1vjxC7/3 here there are all the types of ECO

Comment: Ok, which set of ECO including space is not matching please paste some example here

Comment: ECO-998 RX ECO-8550 UP M , ECO-8550 UP  ECO-8550 B and ignore ECO-DE

Comment: WHAT ABOUT ECOGEST?

Comment: ECOGEST dosent have to match

Comment: @overdex77 watch out the update at the bottom of the answer... I hope, it covers your comments...